# codeigniter - is there a workaround for using flashdata with php sessions?

Tags: codeigniter-2

codeigniter - is there a workaround for using flashdata with php sessions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this library http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/